# Sending data from one Protocol to another Protocol in Twisted?

Tags: python, twisted

One of my protocols is connected to a server, and with the output of that I'd like to send it to the other protocol.

I need to access the 'msg' method in ClassA from ClassB but I keep getting: `exceptions.AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'write'`

Actual code:

```
from twisted.words.protocols import irc
from twisted.internet import protocol
from twisted.internet.protocol import Protocol, ClientFactory
from twisted.internet import reactor

IRC_USERNAME = 'xxx'
IRC_CHANNEL = '#xxx'
T_USERNAME = 'xxx'
T_PASSWORD = md5.new('xxx').hexdigest()

class ircBot(irc.IRCClient):
    def _get_nickname(self):
        return self.factory.nickname

    nickname = property(_get_nickname)

    def signedOn(self):
        self.join(self.factory.channel)
        print "Signed on as %s." % (self.nickname,)

    def joined(self, channel):
        print "Joined %s." % (channel,)

    def privmsg(self, user, channel, msg):
        if not user:
                return

        who = "%s: " % (user.split('!', 1)[0], )
        print "%s %s" % (who, msg)

class ircBotFactory(protocol.ClientFactory):
    protocol = ircBot

    def __init__(self, channel, nickname=IRC_USERNAME):
        self.channel = channel
        self.nickname = nickname

    def clientConnectionLost(self, connector, reason):
        print "Lost connection (%s), reconnecting." % (reason,)
        connector.connect()

    def clientConnectionFailed(self, connector, reason):
        print "Could not connect: %s" % (reason,)

class SomeTClass(Protocol):
    def dataReceived(self, data):
        if data.startswith('SAY'):
                data = data.split(';', 1)
                # RAGE
                #return self.ircClient.msg(IRC_CHANNEL, 'test')

    def connectionMade(self):
        self.transport.write("mlogin %s %s\n" % (T_USERNAME, T_PASSWORD))

class tClientFactory(ClientFactory):
    def startedConnecting(self, connector):
        print 'Started to connect.'

    def buildProtocol(self, addr):
        print 'Connected.'
        return t()

    def clientConnectionLost(self, connector, reason):
        print 'Lost connection.  Reason:', reason

    def clientConnectionFailed(self, connector, reason):
        print 'Connection failed. Reason:', reason

if __name__ == "__main__":
    #chan = sys.argv[1]
    reactor.connectTCP('xxx', 6667, ircBotFactory(IRC_CHANNEL) )
    reactor.connectTCP('xxx', 20184, tClientFactory() )
    reactor.run()
```

Any ideas please? :-)

Comment: Can you paste actual code?
Ideally a minimal non-working example. As is, there could be half a dozen reasons why it's not working.

Comment: sorry - http://pastebin.com/MQPhduSY

Comment: Can you post the full error message also?

Comment: That's still not a working example, by the looks of it. You have a protocol called Toribash which you're not referencing anywhere, and there's a function t() which appears to be undefined.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Twisted [FAQ](http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/wiki/FrequentlyAskedQuestions#HowdoImakeinputononeconnectionresultinoutputonanother):

> ***How do I make input on one connection
>   result in output on another?***
>
> *This seems like it's a Twisted
>   question, but actually it's a Python
>   question. Each Protocol object
>   represents one connection; you can
>   call its transport.write to write some
>   data to it. These are regular Python
>   objects; you can put them into lists,
>   dictionaries, or whatever other data
>   structure is appropriate to your
>   application.*
>
> *As a simple example, add a list to
>   your factory, and in your protocol's
>   connectionMade and connectionLost, add
>   it to and remove it from that list.
>   Here's the Python code:*
>
> ```
> from twisted.internet.protocol import Protocol, Factory
> from twisted.internet import reactor
>
> class MultiEcho(Protocol):
>     def connectionMade(self):
>         self.factory.echoers.append(self)
>     def dataReceived(self, data):
>         for echoer in self.factory.echoers:
>             echoer.transport.write(data)
>     def connectionLost(self, reason):
>         self.factory.echoers.remove(self)
>
> class MultiEchoFactory(Factory):
>     protocol = MultiEcho
>     def __init__(self):
>         self.echoers = []
>
> reactor.listenTCP(4321, MultiEchoFactory())
> reactor.run()
> ```